# VBA - Skip corrupted files

Tags: excel, vba

I copied code from another site that opens every Excel file on a path and sets the password to "".

I have 480 Excel files on that path, and the code stops whenever it encounters a corrupted file.

- Is there a way to identify every file that is corrupted?
- Is there a way to avoid corrupted files?

```vb
Sub RemovePasswords()
    Dim xlBook As Workbook
    Dim strFilename As String
    Const fPath As String = "C:\Path\"        'The folder to process, must end with "\"
    Const strPassword As String = "openpassword"        'case sensitive
    Const strEditPassword As String = "editpassword" 'If no password use ""
    
    strFilename = Dir$(fPath & "*.xls") 'will open xls & xlsx etc
    While Len(strFilename) <> 0
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Set xlBook = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=fPath & strFilename, _
                                    Password:=strPassword, _
                                    WriteResPassword:=strEditPassword)
        xlBook.SaveAs FileName:=fPath & strFilename, _
                      Password:="", _
                      WriteResPassword:="", _
                      CreateBackup:=True
        xlBook.Close 0
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        strFilename = Dir$()
    Wend
End Sub
```

On the other hand, whenever the code encounters a corrupted file it just stops and doesn't let me know which file is corrupted.

I know that there is a way to put a "if" to skip this errors, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next adapted code:

```
Sub RemovePasswords()
Dim xlBook As Workbook, strFilename As String
Const fPath As String = "C:\Path\"               'The folder to process, must end with "\"
Const strPassword As String = "openpassword"     'case sensitive
Const strEditPassword As String = "editpassword" 'If no password use ""
    strFilename = dir$(fPath & "*.xls")          'will open xls & xlsx etc
    While Len(strFilename) <> 0
        On Error Resume Next 'skip the error, if the case
        Set xlBook = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=fPath & strFilename, _
                                    password:=strPassword, _
                                    WriteResPassword:=strEditPassword)
        If err.Number = 0 Then                 'if no error:
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            xlBook.saveas fileName:=fPath & strFilename, _
                          password:="", _
                          WriteResPassword:="", _
                          CreateBackup:=True
            xlBook.Close 0
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0                     'restart raising errors when the case
        strFilename = dir$()
    Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change the code suggested by FaneDuru a little, in order to comply to your first demand. This code will output corrupt filenames in the debug panel.

```
Sub RemovePasswords()
    Dim xlBook As Workbook
    Dim strFilename As String
    Const fPath As String = "C:\Path\" 'The folder to process, must end with "\"
    Const strPassword As String = "openpassword" 'case sensitive
    Const strEditPassword As String = "editpassword" 'If no password use ""
    
    strFilename = Dir$(fPath & "*.xls") 'will open xls & xlsx etc
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    While Len(strFilename) <> 0        
        Set xlBook = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=fPath & strFilename, _
            Password:=strPassword, WriteResPassword:=strEditPassword)
        If err.Number = 0 Then
            xlBook.SaveAs FileName:=fPath & strFilename, _
                Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", CreateBackup:=True
            xlBook.Close 0
        Else
            Debug.Print strFilename 'This will output corrupt filenames in the debug pane
            err.Clear
        End If
        strFilename = Dir$()
    Wend
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```